# Vim autocommand produces E488: Trailing characters

Tags: vim

I'm trying to insert the following autocommand into Vim:

```
autocmd BufEnter *.c :call SourceTagsVim()<CR>

function! SourceTagsVim()
let s:fname = expand('<afile>:p:h') . 'tags.vim'
    if filereadable(s:fname)
        exe 'so ' . s:fname
    else
        echo s:fname " could not be read"
    endif
endfunction
```

But vim keeps telling me the following error message:

```
Error detected while processing BufEnter Auto commands for "*.c":
E488: Trailing charcters
```

But the autocommand executes fine. Any Idea what I'm doing wrong. I also used dos2unix on my vimrc to ensure the correct line endings.

Thanks for the help,
Andreas

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not need the `:` or the `<cr>` as autocommands execute commands.

```
autocmd BufEnter *.c call SourceTagsVim()
```